# Flattening Efficientnet model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, efficientnet

I am trying to remove the top layer in the efficientnet-pytorch implementation. However, if I simply replace the final `_fc` layer with my own fully connected layer, as suggested by the author [in this github comment](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/issues/207#issuecomment-658405446), I am worried that there is still a `swish` activation even after this layer, as opposed to having nothing as I expected. When I print the model, the final lines is as follows:

```py
(_bn1): BatchNorm2d(1280, eps=0.001, momentum=0.010000000000000009, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (_avg_pooling): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
    (_dropout): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
    (_fc): Sequential(
      (0): Linear(in_features=1280, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (1): ReLU()
      (2): Dropout(p=0.25, inplace=False)
      (3): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=128, bias=True)
      (4): ReLU()
      (5): Dropout(p=0.25, inplace=False)
      (6): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=1, bias=True)
    )
    (_swish): MemoryEfficientSwish()
  )
)
```

where `_fc` is my replaced module.

What I hoped to do was:

```py
base_model = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b3')
model = nn.Sequential(*list(base_model.children()[:-3]))
```

where in my mind `base_model.children()` flattens the model from the nested structure. However, now I cannot seem to be able to use the model as if I use a dummy input, `x=torch.randn(1,3,255,255)` I get the error: `TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

It should be noted that `model[:2](x)` works, but not `model[:3](x)`. `model[2]` seems to be the mobile blocks.

Here is a [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WribnIF2keuNUQrRHbtrYWUdQnO_q7rC?usp=sharing) with the above code.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common misunderstanding of what `print(net)` actually does.

The fact that there is a `_swish` Module after the `_fc` simply means that for former was registered after the latter. You can check that in the [code](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/35dbb4b72c2f587ae8b499a9d405939b41929cda/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py#L201-L205):

```py
class EfficientNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, blocks_args=None, global_params=None):

        # [...]

        # Final linear layer
        self._avg_pooling = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
        self._dropout = nn.Dropout(self._global_params.dropout_rate)
        self._fc = nn.Linear(out_channels, self._global_params.num_classes)
        self._swish = MemoryEfficientSwish()
```

The order in which they are defined is the order that they will be printed. When it comes to what exactly is performed, you have to check the [`forward`](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/35dbb4b72c2f587ae8b499a9d405939b41929cda/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py#L287-L306):

```py
def forward(self, inputs):
    # Convolution layers
    x = self.extract_features(inputs)

    # Pooling and final linear layer
    x = self._avg_pooling(x)
    x = x.flatten(start_dim=1)
    x = self._dropout(x)
    x = self._fc(x)

    return x
```

and, as you can see, there is nothing after `self._fc(x)`, which means no `Swish` will be applied.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that. So is the only reliable way to check the order to do `print(inspect.getsource(model.forward))` as of August 2021?